# Best processor for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, hardware

Our web app's db server (running SQL Server 2008) is starting to get pounded and so I would like to upgrade it to a better box. We will still probably be going with a hosted solution.

I know that the more RAM the better, but what about the processor? Is it better to have a multicore processor or one that's a little more server-oriented, like Xeon or Opteron?

Comment: I would suggest moving this question to ServerFault (serverfault.com) see this blog post on information to become part of the ServerFault private beta http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/server-fault-private-beta-begins/

Comment: @Nathan Koop: He doesn't have enough rep yet to become part of ServerFault.

Comment: @JFV good call, forgot about that.

Comment: Rep is not needed, just email team@serverfault.com with your OpenID.  Jeff will figure stuff out for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes having a Xeon processor over a standard processor will help with the overall performance of your SQL Server.  The more major concern would be your RAM.  High-performance RAM will also boost the performance of the SQL Server too.  To top off the performance, you would probably want to get 15k rpm hard disks.

Good rule of thumb, the faster the technology (RAM, Processor, and Hard Drives) the better!

Comment: So are Xeons multi-core? Or do multiple cores not give an advantage for RDBMs?

Comment: Xeon processors are multi-core and they have an additional cache on them to process instructions quickly.  Check this out to find out the differences between the Xeon Models of Processor: http://serverconfigurator.intel.com/compare.aspx?CategoryID=1
The 7400 series has a 16mb L3 Cache

Answer (score 1):

I know it's probably obvious but no-one has mentioned it yet: If possible, go for a 64-bit OS. More memory and is much quicker.

Answer (score 1):

All this talk of better hardware, but no one talking about performance tuning your DB.  Although I must agree with most of the comments, expecially RAM and HD.  More and Faster is always better.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said - More RAM the better. But next most important component is HDDs in RAID.
Probably the "best" is RAID 0+1, sometimes called RAID 10.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to consider is licensing.  Microsoft charges per socket - not per core.  I believe Oracle charges a percentage of a full license per core.  In either case, you could save quite a bit of money by going with fewer sockets holding higher core-count CPUs.